# Infinescroll page not working on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

i made a simple infinetescroll page using its infitescroll jquery library https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js, used kaminari gem for the pagination , "securerandom" ruby library for seeding the database with random data.

It worked fine on the WEBrick local server.

But then i deployed it on Heroku .It was also fine as the database was seeded successfully using heroku run rake db:seed

But it was only paginated and infinescroll was not working ....

i think there is some problem with assets pipeline but not sure and can't figure it out..

Comment: Check your browser console. Are there any JS errors? Also, check heroku logs for errors while deploying.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://morning-mesa-2816.herokuapp.com/assets/application-f0fb82edc7c2184954bbc9aa62909850.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://morning-mesa-2816.herokuapp.com/assets/application-7ab08243b14a2ca9797c4dde97167835.js
3Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://morning-mesa-2816.herokuapp.com/assets/application-f0fb82edc7c2184954bbc9aa62909850.css

Comment: It seems that your application.css is not compiled. Did you get any errors while deploying?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :-

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

And then push the precompiled assets to heroku.